# What does 'a quarter of three' mean in AmE?

Tags: meaning-in-context, american-english

> of
> preposition
> 10 *North American* Expressing time in relation to the following hour.
> *'it would be just a quarter of three in New York'*

(from  Lexico [here](https://www.lexico.com/definition/of))

What is "it"? 2:15 or 2:45? Lexico simply says that in this sense, 'of' "expresses time in relation to the following hour" without elaborating on this.

Comment: It should be: a quarter TO three. But some people say of three.

Comment: I don't see that in the link. A quarter to three **means** 2:45 or a quarter to or of three.

Comment: "the following hour" says exactly that, surely? "15 of three" is 15 minutes from the **following hour**. Is that not clear enough?

Comment: @PrimeMover I edited my question. I misspoke

Comment: it= is called a **dummy pronoun**. It is raining. It is snowing. It is time to leave because it's three o'clock. [or it's]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Lexico definition is unambiguous, though I'll admit that it's a bit wordy and hard to understand for learners.

As you said, the definition is:

> "of" expresses time in relation to the following hour

If we use the actual values in the phrase "a quarter of three," then this means:

> "of" expresses one quarter hour in relation to **the following hour** of 3:00

I've emphasized **the following hour** because this tells us that we are talking about the quarter-hour that **precedes** 3:00, which is 2:45.

A clearer definition could be:

> "of" expresses a short time span **before** an hour

Note that even in AmE, this is a regionalism - it's common in the Northeast and rarer elsewhere.  It comes very naturally to me because I grew up using it, but when I moved to Canada, I had to train myself *not* to say "five of nine" to mean 8:55 because nobody here understands this expression.

Comment: My grandmother (in the US) used to use *a quarter of* all the time. I remember when I was quite young having great difficulty understanding what it meant. For some reason, I never actually looked at a clock when she said it, but simply remained confused. I later did learn that when she (and others in the US) said *a quarter of three*, they actually meant *a quarter **to** three*, or 2:45.

Comment: @Lambie - This is not a useful complaint. What exactly do you find confusing and how could this answer be improved?

Comment: Look at the way I structured my answer. You start with the question, and go from there leaving the comments to the end. But now he has CHANGED the question.

Comment: @Lambie - I think the reason you're getting downvotes is that you didn't address/explain the Lexico definition, which was in the OP's original question even before he changed it.

Comment: But I did. Look at my last line. I provided the principle of the thing.

Answer (score 4):

It’s 2:45.

A quarter of an hour before 3:00.

Comment: Whatever. I find it clunky.

Answer (score -2):

3:45 =

- a quarter **to** four [one way to say it]
- a quarter **of** four [another way to say it]
- **three forty five**
- a quarter to [the hour is left out sometimes]

3:15

- a **quarter past three**
- a **quarter past**
- **three fifteen**

The OP changed his numbers. So, change yours accordingly and stop the downvotes which make no sense at all. These are standard ways to express time in English!

**So, if it's 2:45, it's a quarter to three, etc.**

It's 5 o'clock. It's 4:45. It is called a **dummy pronoun** found in sentences for time or the weather or general statements.